# Formatting output with Knitr, ggplot2 and xtable

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, knitr, xtable

I am trying to achieve the following task with Knitr, ggplot2 and xtables:

- Generate several annotated plots of beta-distributions with ggplot2
- Write the output in a layout such that I have a plot, and a corresponding summary Stats table following it, for every plot.
- Write the code such that both PDF and HTML reports can be a generated in a presentable way

Here is my attempt at this task (Rnw file):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Test for ggplot2 with Knitr

<<Initialize, echo=FALSE>>=
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(data.table)
library(grid)
library(xtable)
library (plyr)

pltlist <- list()
statlist <- list()

@

The libraries are loaded. Now run the main loop


<<plotloop, echo=FALSE>>=
    for (k in seq(1,7)){
      x <- data.table(rbeta(100000,1.6,14+k))
      xmean <- mean(x$V1, na.rm=T)
      xqtl <- quantile(x$V1, probs = c(0.995), names=F)
      xdiff <- xqtl - xmean
      dens <- density(x$V1)
      xscale <- (max(dens$x, na.rm=T) - min(dens$x, na.rm=T))/100
      yscale <- (max(dens$y, na.rm=T))/100
      y_max <- max(dens$y, na.rm=T)
      y_intercept <- y_max-(10*yscale)
      data <- data.frame(x)

      y <- ggplot(data, aes(x=V1)) + geom_density(colour="darkgreen", size=2, fill="green",alpha=.3) +
        geom_vline(xintercept = xmean, colour="blue", linetype = "longdash") +
        geom_vline(xintercept = xqtl, colour="red", linetype = "longdash") +
        geom_segment(aes(x=xmean, xend=xqtl, y=y_intercept, yend=y_intercept), colour="red", linetype = "solid", arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, "cm"), ends = "both", type = "closed")) +
        annotate("text", x = xmean+xscale, y = y_max, label = paste("Val1:",round(xmean,4)), hjust=0) +
        annotate("text", x = xqtl+xscale, y = y_max, label = paste("Val2:",round(xqtl,4))) +
        annotate("text", x = xmean+10*xscale, y = y_max-15*yscale, label = paste("Val3:",round(xdiff,4))) +
        xlim(min(dens$x, na.rm=T), xqtl + 9*xscale) +
        xlab("Values") +
        ggtitle("Beta Distribution") +
        theme_bw() +
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0, vjust=2))

      pltlist[[k]] <- y
      statlist[[k]] <- list(mean=xmean, quantile=xqtl) 

}

stats <- ldply(statlist, data.frame)
@

Plots are ready. Now Plot them

<<PrintPlots, warning=FALSE, results='asis', echo=FALSE, cache=TRUE,  fig.height=3.5>>=
for (k in seq(1,7)){
  print(pltlist[[k]])
  print(xtable(stats[k,], caption="Summary Statistics", digits=6))
}

@

Plotting Finished.


\end{document}
```

I am faced with several issues after running this code.

1. When I run this code just as R code, Once I try to print the plots in the list, the horizontal line from the `geom_segment` part starts to move all over the place. However if I plot the figures individually, without putting them in a list, the figures are fine, as I would expect them to be.
2. Only the last plot is as I would expect the output to be, in all the other plots, the `geom_segment` line moves around randomly.
3. I am also unable to put a separate caption for the Plots as I can for the Tables.

Points to note :

- I am storing the beta-random numbers in data.table since in our actual code, we are using data.table. However for the purposes of testing ggplot2 in this way, I convert the data.table into a data.frame, as ggplot2 requires.
- I also need to generate the random numbers within the loop and generate the plots per iteration (so something like first generating the random numbers and then using `melt` would not work here), since generating the random numbers is emulating a complex database call per iteration of the loop.

I am using RStudio Version 0.98.1091  and
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) on Windows 8.1

This is the expected Plot:
[image: Expected Plot]

This is the plot I am getting when plotting from the list:
[image: Plot from the list]

My output in PDF form :
[PDF Output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c3um8ojxrknief0/ggplotTest.pdf?dl=0)

Please advice if there are any ideas for solutions.

Thank you,

SG

Comment: 1. It appears you're using Sweave to generate the output. I don't see substantial LaTeX in your code, so the Knitr package may be better for your purpose. Knitr is able to output PDF and HTML documents.      
2. The links to "Expected Plot" and "Plot from the list" are broken.

Comment: Thanks for the comment zhaoy. I rectified the code to work with knitr. I don't know why the links for the figures are not working directly. However if you right click and open image in a new tab, the images seem to be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the horizontal line in `geom_segment` is "moving around" from plot to plot, rather than spanning `xmean` to `xqtl`. However, I was able to get the horizontal line in the correct location by getting the value from the `stats` data frame, rather than from direct calculation of the mean and quantile. You just have to create the `stats` data frame before the loop, rather than after, so that you can use it in the loop.

```
  stats <- ldply(statlist, data.frame)

  for (k in seq(1,7)){
    ...

    y <- ggplot(data, aes(x=V1)) + 
        ...
        geom_segment(aes(x=stats[k,1], xend=stats[k,2], y=y_intercept, yend=y_intercept), 
                 colour="red", linetype = "solid", 
                 arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, "cm"), ends = "both", type = "closed")) +
        ...

  pltlist[[k]] <- y
  statlist[[k]] <- list(mean=xmean, quantile=xqtl) 
  }
```

Hopefully, someone else will be able to explain the anomalous behavior, but at least this seems to fix the problem.

For the figure caption, you can add a `fig.cap` argument to the chunk where you plot the figures, although this results in the same caption for each figure and causes the figures and tables to be plotted in separate groups, rather than interleaved:

```
<<PrintPlots, warning=FALSE, results='asis', echo=FALSE, cache=TRUE, fig.cap="Caption", fig.height=3.5>>=
for (k in seq(1,7)){
  print(pltlist[[k]])
  print(xtable(stats[k,], caption="Summary Statistics", digits=6))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to go through the problem eipi10 :)  Your solution works for the problem on the x-axis. I tried to fix it similarly for the y-axis but without success. `geom_segment` must be expecting a dataframe for both the x and y coordinates. So I tried something like this : `geom_segment(aes(x=x_coords[1,1], xend=x_coords[1,2], y=y_coords[1,1], yend=y_coords[1,1]))`, setting up the variables as follows: `y_coords <- data.frame(y_max-(10*yscale))` and `x_coords <- data.frame(c(xmean, xqtl))` , just before the statement `y <- ggplot( ...` within the loop. Problem still persists..

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use R Markdown and knitr which is easier than using LaTeX and R (as also zhaoy suggested).

You might also want to check out the [ReporteRs](http://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/index.html) package. I think it is actually easier to use than knitr. However, you cannot generate PDFs with it. But you can use pandoc to convert them into PDFs.

Comment: I found that the OP's code runs fine with `knitr` in `RStudio`, creating a PDF file exactly as expected. The incorrect position of the horizontal line doesn't seem to be a `knitr` issue, as it happens whether I run the code interactively or through `knitr`.

Comment: Thanks Caner. I will try out the ReporteRs package. However as eipi is saying, the code seems to do fine with knitr and Rstudio, except for the horizontal line. I will will try out ReporteRs as well as soon as I can